# Highcharts - Rotate pie chart aligning the clicked section to a fixed point (180°)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I am dealing with a request regarding the possibility of rotating a pie chart created with highcharts.js once the user clicks on a portion of the pie.
Giving a fixed point, which has an angle of 180 degrees, the pie should align itself pointing the clicked section towards that fixed point, represented by a triangle in my case. So, every time the user clicks on a section, the fixed triangle points at it, as the pie rotates.
I have already managed to catch the click event and change the `startAngle` option like this:

```
// Rotate chart
donutChart.series[0].update({
    startAngle: convertAngle("rads", this.angle) // gives the point angle in rads
});
```

which is obviously wrong, but I would like to do something like that in the point-events-click event.

Do you have any suggestions in order to achieve this (if that is even possible)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cool question.

Your rotation algorithm is a bit flawed.  Say, for example, you want the startAngle to be such that it rotates your **3rd** slice to start at 0 degrees (top of the chart).  This would be:

```
-(slice1ArcDegrees + slice2ArcDegrees)
```

The ArcDegrees can be found by:

```
 (percentage/100.0 * 360.0)
```

Putting this together in the point click handler:

```
  var points = this.series.points;
  var startAngle = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
    var p = points[i];
    if (p == this)
    {
      break;
    }
    startAngle += (p.percentage/100.0 * 360.0);
  }
  this.series.update({
    startAngle: -startAngle + 180 - ((this.percentage/100.0 * 360.0)/2) // center at 180
  });
```

Here's an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ONYANza2Aigq6Qx9dKEt?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you for your proposal. Let's say I want to have the slice always oriented towards the "south" position (180°), like I said. How should I modify your code in order to do that? I can see from your example that the slices always start from 0 when I click them, but they are not centered in position 0.

Comment: @AlexKibo88, just use `startAngle: -startAngle + 180` to start at 180 degrees, or `startAngle: -startAngle + 180 - ((this.percentage/100.0 * 360.0)/2)` to center slice at 180 degrees, see udpated example: http://plnkr.co/edit/ONYANza2Aigq6Qx9dKEt?p=preview

Comment: May I also ask you how to set the startAngle in order to have the biggest slice pointing the 180° fixed origin?

Comment: @AlexKibo88, see updates here: http://plnkr.co/edit/ONYANza2Aigq6Qx9dKEt?p=preview